# Finding parameters that give a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $L: \textbf{R}^3 \rightarrow \textbf{R}^3$ be defined by $L([x,y,z]) = [ax^2 + bx, cy + z, d]$.

Which of the following choices of the parameters $a, b, c, d$ gives a linear transformation?

A.  $a = 1, b = 2, c = 3, d = 0$

B. $a = 0, b = 1, c = 0, d = 1$

C. $a = 0, b = 2, c = 4, d = 0$

D. $a = 1, b = 0, c = 0, d = 1$

E. $a = b = c = d = 1$

The solutions I have looked at online all say C is the answer because a and d need to be equal to zero, but none of them explain it. Why do $a$ and $d$ need to equal zero?

Comment: Try yourself the check the axioms, say for $A$.

Comment: Hint: for $T$ to be linear, you must have $T(0) = 0$, or in coordinates, you must have $T([0,0,0]) = [0,0,0]$. What's that tell you about $d$?

Comment: For $T$ to be linear is should also fulfill $T(\alpha v+\beta w)=\alpha(v)+\beta T(w)$

Comment: @mymemesarespiciest Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

- $a$ is on a non linear term
- take $d\neq 0$ and check $L(u+v)=L(u)+L(v)$

Answer (score 0):

Every component of $L(x,y,z)$ must be a linear combination of the variables $x$, $y$ and $z$. So you must have $a = d =0$, while $b$ and $c$ can be anything.